# SQL Server: The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table

Tags: sql-server

I've read the article http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/ but one thin is not clear enough for me

Suppose I want to use "Tally table" in my procedure, and my co-worker planning to use "Tally table" in his procedure.
Do we have to use different Tally table for each procedure.
If it so, I think it will be so many different "Tally tables" in our database (one Tally table on each procedure).
If we could use the only Tally table for each procedure then how to fill this table sequential data? I need 1000 rows, somebody else can decide that it's too much and decrease the amount...

Please clear this moment for me...

Comment: Just use one table. If somebody decrease the content and ruins it for others, smack them with a rolled up newspaper and say "bad programmer"

Comment: In other words: to guaranty the absent of such errors I have to move Tally table in other scheme with very big amount of records where ordinary programmer can't delete records.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason you couldn't use the same table in multiple procedures or by different people. If you only need 1000 rows for you query and it doenst run multiple times per second you could consider creating and populating it in your query as a temp table because 1000 rows of just an incremental number is nothing to the engine.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion about temp table. I think it useful.